# How to instruct GraphicsMagick to convert using profile and filter IPTC data to a subset?

Tags: typo3, profile, converters, graphicsmagick

I'm using GraphicsMagick with TYPO3 to convert files and would like to get a new file as result, that has only a subset of IPTC data left. So would like to keep only the creator, title, description and copyright information, removing all other data.

When specifying $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['processor_stripColorProfileCommand'] = '+profile '!iptc,*''; I get everything from IPTC as expected. Is there a possibility to specify something like this:

+profile '!iptc.creator,!iptc.description,*' or
+profile '!iptc:creator,!iptc:description,*' or
something similar to filter the data?

I tried ., :, -, small Caps, lower-/uppercase but got no result.

Comment: If you share a file with the required IPTC metadata (probably using Dropbox or Google Drive) I will have a try...

Comment: I've got a file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZqimYl9JwsZxcSsE5XCRHtoSaKajC5b/view?usp=share_link 

It has a title, description, creator, copyright and comments. With the correct settings the comments should be gone on the new files.

thx in advance.

Comment: There is no access to read that file for me